# EmptyDataError while scraping with selenium and joblib although data are there

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, joblib

I am scraping a pool of urls with selenium/geckodriver and joblib in paralell:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=40)(delayed(scrape)(URL) for URL in final_url_list)
```

The current challenge is that I am getting `EmptyDataError` for for a significant amount of joblib runs/URLs although I know the data are there and online.

My temporary solution is to repeat the iteration/run whenever `EmptyDataError` comes up:

```
def scrape(URL):
    while True:
        try:
            scraping_logic[...]                                    # Do the scraping
        except EmptyDataError:                                     # handle EmptyDataError
            print "scraping failed due to unknown reason - repeat" # notify
            continue                                               # repeat scraping this URL 
        else: 
            break                                                  # finish
```

However, I keep having ~20 repeats for some URLs in extreme cases. Therefore, this solution is not optimal.

**Q1: What is the cause of this error, given that the to-be-scraped data are in fact there?**

**Q2: How to tweak the code to minimize the chance of wasting time on too many repeating iterations?**

*Note that this error also comes up in the same frequency when I run joblib with `n_jobs = 1`, therefore we can exclude the root cause to be too many joblib workers.*